# Infinitely shrinkable glue except if surrounded by text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, plain-tex

Say `\a` and `\b` are two macros that expand to some text and either one may be `\empty` but not both.
I want to put `\a` and `\b` in a line, centered and separated by a `\quad`.

```
\hfil\a\quad\b\hfil
```

Problem: if one of `\a` or `\b` are `\empty`, then the `\quad` prevents the text from being properly centered. Ideally I would need some glue between `\a` and `\b` that would shrink to zero if it came in direct contact with infinitely stretchable glue.

Comment: `\hfil \a\quad \b\unskip \hfil` can handle the "empty \b" case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The definitions `\a` and `\b` can be tested, whether they are `\empty`:

```
\a
\ifx\a\empty
\else
  \ifx\b\empty
  \else
    \quad
  \fi
\fi
\b
```

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the \quad before an empty \b with \unskip. You can test for an empty \a by checking the \gluestretchorder of \lastskip:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\def\a{balbalbablabl} \def\b{balbalbablabl}

\hfil\a\ifnum\gluestretchorder\lastskip>0\else\quad\fi\b\unskip \hfil

\def\a{balbalbablabl} \def\b{}

\hfil\a\ifnum\gluestretchorder\lastskip>0\else\quad\fi\b\unskip \hfil

\def\a{} \def\b{balbalbablabl}

\hfil\a\ifnum\gluestretchorder\lastskip>0\else\quad\fi\b\unskip \hfil

\hfil balbalbablabl\hfil

\end{document}
```